# TypeScript: exports.__esModule = true Uncaught ReferenceError: exports is not defined

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, electron, node-modules

when i run code in console brings an error "Uncaught ReferenceError: exports is not defined at render.js". when i click her in i see this `exports.__esModule = true;`
what should i do to solve this problem?
TypeScript: exports.__esModule = true Uncaught ReferenceError: exports is not defined
I'm trying to export and import with typescript but it doesn't work can you help?
I have tried various remedies but it didn't work
This is my first typescript project

renderer.ts

```
    import Upload from "./js/Upload";
    import Analysis from "./js/Analysis";
    let GetName = <HTMLInputElement>document.getElementById("FileUpload");
    let Button = document.getElementById("UploadButton")
    GetName.addEventListener("change", Upload)
    Button.addEventListener("click", Analysis)
```

Upload.ts

```
    let GetName = <HTMLInputElement>document.getElementById("FileUpload");
    let Button = document.getElementById("UploadButton")
    export default function Upload() {
    }
```

Analysis.ts

```
    export default function Analysis() {
      console.log("Analysis")
    }
```

package.json

```
    {
      "devDependencies": {
        "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^4.33.0",
        "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^4.33.0",
        "electron": "^24.3.0",
        "eslint": "^7.32.0",
        "typescript": "^4.8.3"
      },
      "dependencies": {
        "xlsx": "^0.18.5"
      }
    }
```

tsconfig.json

```
    {
      "compilerOptions": {
        "module": "commonjs",
        "noImplicitAny": true,
        "sourceMap": false,
        "outDir": "dist",
        "baseUrl": ".",
        "paths": {
          "*": ["node_modules/*"]
        }
      },
      "include": [
        "src/**/*"
      ]
    }
```

Comment: Please provide more context, what is the exact errors and what are the exact steps you take to get to them?

Comment: hen i run code in console brings an error "Uncaught ReferenceError: exports is not defined at render.js". when i click her in i see this exports.__esModule = true; what should i do to solve this problem?

Comment: You say "render.js", do you mean "rendering.js"? If so, why is there to `exports` string in any of your code? Also, if its es modules, it would be `export` and not `exports`?

Comment: What is "console"?E.g. you can't run that in chrome console

Comment: To add a little explanation to Dimava's note. Typescript needs to be combined to JavaScript in order to run in the browser (console). You need a compiler (typically tsc) to do this. Please see the TypeScript documentation on how to this.